# How to if !something

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm just learning GAE, Python and Django and have a problem with my Django template. I understand the GAE version of Django is 0.96 and so predates a lot of the fancy {% if x == False %} stuff.

All I want to do is:

```
{% if NOT variable.approved %}
  This should render if the approved property is False
{% end if %}
```

The approved property is a `db.BooleanProperty(default=False, required=True)` in my DataStore.

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code per the formattting guidelines on the right hand side of the new question / answer pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do `{% if not variable.approved %}`. This is explained in, for example, the [1.1 documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if).

Note that you can install Django 1.2 in GAE, if you want.